# Prove that if $n$ is not a square, then $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational by complete induction.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is not a square, then $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.

I did the proof of the contrapositive using the principle of complete induction:

proof. Suppose that $\sqrt{n}$, for $n> 1$, is rational. Then $\sqrt{n}=\dfrac{b}{q}$, where $b,q \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus $n = \dfrac{b^{2}}{q^{2}}$ implies that $nq^{2}=b^{2}.$ Using the fact that any natural number can be written as a product of primes, we have that $b=p_{1} \cdot p_{2} \cdots p_{k}$ and thus $b^{2}=(p_{1} \cdot p_{2} \cdots p_{k})^{2}=p_{1}^{2} \cdot p_{2}^{2} \cdots p_{k}^{2}$ (for primes $p_{1},...,p_{k}$ not necessarily distinct). For any prime $p_{r}$, $1\le r<k$, we can partition $b^{2}$ in $k-1$ ways as follows:

$p_{1}^{2}\cdot q_{1}^{2}$,

$p_{1}^{2}\cdot p_{2}^{2}q_{2}^{2}=(p_{1}\cdot p_{2})^{2}q_{2}^{2},$

$\vdots$

$p_{1}^{2}\cdots p_{k-1}^{2}q_{k-1}^{2}=(p_{1}\cdots p_{k-1})^{2}q_{k-1}^{2},$

Multiplying each of the given $k-1$ partitions by the square of some prime $p_{k}$, it follows that $n$ is necessarily a square in each of the $k-1$ partitions. Since $n=2$ is not a square, $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. By the principal of complete induction, it follows that if $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is not a square, then $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational. QED

I wanted to know if there are any major problems with the proof that I've provided, or if there are ways I can improve the proof.

Comment: What does "$n$ is a square in each partition" mean? Why can't your proof show "If $n$ is not a cube then $\sqrt n$ is irrational"?

Comment: Since you ask for improvements. One way to improve the proof is to prove something stronger by essentially the same technique. In your case, the same approach gives [Gauss' lemma on primitive polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)). This result becomes a special case.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I meant that $n$ looks like $p_{1}^{2}$ or $(p_{1}\cdot p_{2})^{2}$ for example.

Comment: @Kapil: It looks interesting. Although, I'll probably have to go through it a few times before I really understand it and how it connects to the proof that I've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter and sweeter... proof by contradition:

Suppose $\sqrt{2} = \frac{a}{b}$ for some reduced integers $a$ and $b$.

Then $2 b^2 = a^2$.

The left-hand side has an odd number of prime factors and the right-hand side has an even number of prime factors.

From the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (unique prime decomposition), this is a contradiction.

Clearly this argument holds for any number that has an odd number of prime factors (allowing multiplicity), and hence for all primes (which have multiplicity = 1).

It also holds for any number that has an odd number of a prime factor, such as $6$, where you merely count the number of a given prime factor (e.g., $2$ or $3$) on each side of the equation.  It even works for $12$ which has just a single factor of (prime) $3$.

Comment: Uh... what if $n \ne 2$

Comment: Same effect. (At least one of) the factors of n is present an odd number of times, with the same conclusion.